# how to get setstate value from one componet to another by clicking in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have two component.1. App.js 2. component/Quiz component
I want to get setstate value of quiz component from Init component by clicking the button on Quiz component using REACT JS.

I want setstate.isFinished value from quiz.js to App.js

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6vcqt8)

Comment: What you have tried so far in code provide it here

Comment: @Atchaya please provide some code to understand your problem, or you can pass value and function from parent to child and handle.

Comment: Do you want to set state for `Init` component from `Quiz` component?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the `state` value as `props` to Quiz Component.

Answer (score 0):

pass a function from the parent component as a prop on the child component being QuizComponent:

In parent:

```
function updateValue(e) {
   console.info(e.currentTarget.value);
   ...
}
```

Pass this as prop on child:

```
<QuizComponent updateValue={this.updateValue} />
```

inside your QuizComponent:

```
<button onClick={this.props.updateValue} value=“10” />
```